# Exception occurred while executing exported method getCurrentPositionAsync Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play-services

I'm using expo location module, It was just working fine, now I'm getting the error

```
[Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getCurrentPositionAsync on module ExpoLocation: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocation
ProviderClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears in /data/app/~~3vyWg7s9RwJ99lUbw2dcmg==/com.thotsuya.medlaapp-xjcjrh20AevFazVYU2oXvg==/base.apk!classes6.dex)]
```

Here's my version of the module

```
"expo-location": "~15.1.1",
```

My code

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (isEnabled) {
            (async () => {

                try {
                    setLoading(true)
                    let {status} = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
                    if (status !== 'granted') {
                        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
                        return;
                    }

                    let loc = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
                    setLocation(loc);


                    await setCurrentProfileStatus(loc?.coords.latitude, loc?.coords.longitude, ProfileStatus.Online)
                    await fetchNearbyPeople(loc?.coords.latitude, loc?.coords.longitude)

                    mapRef.current.animateCamera({
                        center: {
                            latitude: loc?.coords.latitude,
                            longitude: loc?.coords.longitude,
                        },
                    })

                    setLoading(false)
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                } finally {
                    setLoading(false)
                }

            })();
        } else {
            //Update the user's status to offline
            (async () => {
                try {
                    await setCurrentProfileStatus(location?.coords.latitude, location?.coords.longitude, ProfileStatus.Offline)
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            })();
        }
    }, [isEnabled]);
```

Didn't even updated my packages or anything, I'll appreciate any help or advice